# Can anyone explain this snippet of `ruby`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

Can any one explain this snippet of `ruby` ?

```
def request_phase
     service_url = append_params( callback_url, return_url )
    [

      302,
      {
        'Location' => login_url( service_url ),
        'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
      },
      ["You are being redirected to CAS for sign-in."]
    ]
  end
```

Comment: it's a function that returns an array. (ruby returns last expression unless you explicitly return before that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service_url becomes assigned to the output of the append_params method

then request_phase returns an array with 3 things in it:

1. integer: 302
2. hash: containing 'Location' and 'Content-Type' keys (includes service_url, ascertained by append_params)
3. array: containing one element 'You are being redirected..'